# .NET Parsing string into DateTime

Tags: .net

I have a string which is a representation of DateTime:

string dateTime = "20110801";

Now I want to use DateTime.Parse(dateTime);

It throws an Exception stating that dateTime is not in a valid format.

Can anyone tell me how it can be done??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx), which takes in the format as a parameter.

For example:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("20110801", "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
```

Comment: SLaks beat me. Always a bridesmaid, never a bride.

Comment: Thanks both of you for answering my question. That was the simplest solution I needed.

Answer (score 5):

You need to call `ParseExact` with the format string `yyyyMMdd`.