# Problem with Date & time format on server

Tags: string, time, format

I'm having a problem trying to filter a list between 2 dates. I have a solution running on our local machine .NET 3.5. The solution runs fine without any errors. But when I put it on our server (2008) I get

System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

I can recreate the problem locally if I change my machines date/time format from English (United Kingdom) to English (United states).

The problem is I've set the server setting to exactly the same as the local solution and I am still getting the errors.

The code involved is

```
public DateTime StartDate
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.ViewState["StartDate"] != null)
            {
                return DateTime.Parse(this.ViewState["StartDate"].ToString());     
            }
            else { return DateTime.Today.AddYears(-1); }
        }
        private set
        {
            this.ViewState["StartDate"] = value.ToString();
        }
    }

    public DateTime EndDate
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.ViewState["EndDate"] != null)
            {
                return DateTime.Parse(this.ViewState["EndDate"].ToString());
            }
            else { return DateTime.Today; }
        }
        private set
        {
            this.ViewState["EndDate"] = value.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Use ParseExact.  This will allow you to specify a date format, irrespective of the machine's locale.

Lots of questions on Stack Overflow.

[.NET Parsing string into DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6061892/net-parsing-string-into-datetime)

Comment: Hi Paul thanks for that. I'm the business owner so I'll pass this onto our developer.

Answer (score 0):

Hej, try specifying the culture info to the `DateTime.Parse` method, ex:

```
DateTime.Parse(dateString, new CultureInfo("en-US", false))
```

more here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx